# Difference between train and adapt in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, neural-network, perceptron

What is the difference between `train` and `adapt` in MATLAB?

From [MATLAB Answers](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95578-what-are-the-difference-between-adapt-and-train):

> The difference between these training methods is that ADAPT is optimized for situations where the order in which the data is presented matters...

But how to understand it in the following code and result?

```matlab
% MATLAB R2018b (9.5.0.944444) Pro
clear all; close all; clc;
% === Input ===
% Training sample of 15 points
P = [ 3  5  4  6 -4 -2 -4 -3  6  6  8  7 -2 -4 -2 -3;
     -1 -1 -3  1 -2 -2 -4 -4  9  6  6  4  6  4  4  2];
% Results of classification of training sample points
T1 = [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]; % Classification I (left to right)
T2 = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]; % Classification II (top-down)
% Classification I graph of the points of the training sample
figure(1);
plotpv(P, T1);
% Classification II graph of the points of the training sample
figure(2);
plotpv(P, T2);
% Test sample
A = [0  1 -1;
     1 -1 -1];
% Minimum and maximum coordinate values
min_c = min([-10, P(1, :), P(2, :)]);
max_c = max([+10, P(1, :), P(2, :)]);

% === Perceptron  ===
net = newp([min_c max_c; min_c max_c], 2);
% Max. number of epochs for training: 50
net.trainParam.epochs = 50;
% Network training

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
net = train(net, P, [T1; T2]);
% OR
%for i=1:100
%   [net, ~, e] = adapt(net, P, [T1; T2]);
%end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Simulation
a = sim(net, A);
% Visualization
figure(3);
plotpv(horzcat(A, P), horzcat(a, [T1; T2]));
axis([min_c max_c min_c max_c]);
plotpc(net.IW{1}, net.b{1});
grid on;
%...
```

[image]

[image]

Results differ.
Now let's change the location of the points in the array P and T1, T2.

```matlab
% Training sample of 15 points
P = [-4 -2 -4 -3  6  6  8  7 -2 -4 -2 -3  3  5  4  6;
     -2 -2 -4 -4  9  6  6  4  6  4  4  2 -1 -1 -3  1];
% Results of classification of training sample points
T1 = [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]; % Classification I (left to right)
T2 = [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]; % Classification II (top-down)
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

**What I see is that the result of train has changed, the result of adapt has not changed. Why?**
**And why are the results different?**

Comment: well, the order in which you input the data matters for adapt and not for train. what is the question again.

Comment: But the result of train is still fully correct. Your problem has infinite correct solutions, and you train with stochastic methods, therefore you will each time get a random output. You may me misunderstanding what it `adapt` is trying to do? Adapt is designed to go training as the data gets in, but this is a property of the data. Your data, a clustering, has meaningless ordering.

Comment: @ander-biguri I think I understand you.